# OpenJPA Insert not using foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa, openjpa

I'm trying to create a little project around EJB / JPA linked to a Mysql database.
I got two tables FctData and RefKpiDataQuery linked by a foreign key.

FctData :

```
public class FctData implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "DATA_ID")
    private Long dataId;

    ...

    @JoinColumn(name = "DATA_QUERY_REF", referencedColumnName = "KPI_DATA_QUERY_ID")
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private RefKpiDataQuery dataQueryRef;
```

RefKpiDataQuery :

```
public class RefKpiDataQuery implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "KPI_DATA_QUERY_ID")
    private Long kpiDataQueryId;

    ...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "dataQueryRef")
    private Set<FctData> fctDataSet;
```

I got a client which is just trying to insert a FctData in the database

```
RefKpiDataQuery refKpiDataQuery = new RefKpiDataQuery();
refKpiDataQuery.setKpiDataQueryId((long) 2);

FctData fctData = new FctData();
fctData.setDataQueryRef(refKpiDataQuery);

fctDataFacade.insert(fctData);
```

The Facade is a kind of DAO.
This thing is working great with object which don't have a FK.

Here is the error that i get in my log :

```
Field 'DATA_QUERY_REF' doesn't have a default value {prepstmnt 7235700 INSERT INTO FCT_DATA(DATA_DATE, DATA_TIME, DATA_VALIDITY, DATA_VALUE, ISACTIVE, UPDATE_OWNER, UPDATE_TS) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

As we can see in my insert it never talks about the dataQuery.
Someone can explain me what did i miss ? I can't find my mistake.

Thanks for your time.
Cheers

Comment: Have you tried setting `optional = false` on the ManyToOne?

Comment: If the RefKpiDataQuery is existing, have you tried using em.find to look it up rather than creating an empty RefKpiDataQuery instance with that pk value?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I finally got it work by deletting all the optional=false, there is no need to add the cascade.ALL also. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it work by deleting all the

```java
@Basic(optional = false)
```

Also there is no need to add the cascade = CascadeType.ALL